# MySql Query Intersect on 3 tables

Tags: mysql

```
Sailor(sid,sname,rating,age)
Boat(bid,bname,color)
Reserve(sid,bid day)
```

find the sailor who reserved red and green boat? Intersect

I know that intersect does not work in mysql so i am looking for alternatives

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: try JOINS - read about INNER and OUTER

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways other than INTERSECT. You can use JOINS , SUBQUERIES instead of INTERSECT. Following is EQUI JOIN Query, this is just prompt to find the sailor who reserved red and green boat, you can apply the best after reading the comments link:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Sailor as s,
     Boat as b,
     Reserve as r   
WHERE 
    s.sid = r.sid AND 
    b.bid = r.rid AND 
    b.color LIKE 'red' AND 
    b.color LIKE 'green
```